# How to do poll values from Priority queue based on a condition

Tags: java-8, priority-queue, treemap, treeset, top-n

I have map Map<String, PriorityQueue> where the queue is ordered based on the score (reverse). I populated the map from a List where key being data.getGroup and value being Dataitself.

Now my usecase is,

1. if the size of the map is  <=3, I just want to return the Data object so I am just doing a poll top values(Data object) for each key and
2. if the size of the map is > 3 then I need to get 3 values(1 value/key) from the map based on the score.

For eg:

```
// output should be just Data(17.0, "five", "D"), Data(4.0, "two", "A"), Data(3.0, "three", "B") though there will be only 4 keys (A,B,C,D) 
      ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
        dataList.add(new Data(1.0, "one", "A"));
        dataList.add(new Data(4.0, "two", "A"));
        dataList.add(new Data(3.0, "three", "B"));
        dataList.add(new Data(2.0, "four", "C"));
        dataList.add(new Data(7.0, "five", "D"));
        dataList.add(new Data(17.0, "five", "D"));
        
// output should be just Data(5.0, "six", "A"), Data(3.14, "two", "B"), Data(3.14, "three", "C") as there will be only 3 keys (A,B,C)
      ArrayList<Data> dataList2 = new ArrayList<Data>();
        dataList2.add(new Data(3.0, "one", "A"));
        dataList2.add(new Data(5.0, "six", "A"));
        dataList2.add(new Data(3.14, "two", "B"));
        dataList2.add(new Data(3.14, "three", "C"));
```

I tried the below, but is there a better/smarter (optimized) way to do it in Java?

```
// n = 3
public List<Data> getTopN(final List<Data> dataList, final int n) {

   private static final Comparator< Data > comparator = Comparator.comparing(Data::getScore).reversed();

   Map<String, PriorityQueue<Data>> map = Maps.newHashMap();

   for (Data data : dataList) {
            String key = data.getGroup();

            if (key != null) {
                if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
                    map.put(key, new PriorityQueue<>(comparator));
                }
                map.get(key).add(data);
            }
     } 
     
     if (map.size <= n) {
         List<Data> result = new ArrayList<Data>();
      
         for (Map.Entry<String, PriorityQueue<Data>> entrySet: map.entrySet()){

               PriorityQueue<Data> priorityQueue = entrySet.getValue();
               result.add(priorityQueue.peek());
               
         }
      return result;
     } else if (map.size > n) {
    
              List<Data> result = new ArrayList<Data>();
      
         for (Map.Entry<String, PriorityQueue<Data>> entrySet: map.entrySet()){

               PriorityQueue<Data> priorityQueue = entrySet.getValue();
               result.add(priorityQueue.peek());
               
         }

         return result.stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Data::getScore).reversed())
               .limit(n)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Data Object looks like this:

```
public class Data {
     double score;
     String name; 
     String group;
     
      
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
     
    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }
    
    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
     
    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
    
    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You said “I have map `Map<String, PriorityQueue>`”, but in your example code, the starting point is a `List<Data>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your starting point is a `List<Data>`, there’s not much sense in adding the elements to a `Map<String, PriorityQueue<Data>>` when all you’re interested in is one value, i.e. the maximum value, per key. In that case, you can simply store the maximum value.

Further, it’s worth considering the differences between the map methods `keySet()`, `values()`, and `entrySet()`. Using the latter is only useful when you’re interested in both, key and value, within the loop’s body. Otherwise, use either `keySet()` or `values()` to simplify the operation.

Only when trying to get the top *n* values from the map, using a `PriorityQueue` may improve the performance:

```java
private static final Comparator<Data> BY_SCORE = Comparator.comparing(Data::getScore);
private static final BinaryOperator<Data> MAX = BinaryOperator.maxBy(BY_SCORE);

public List<Data> getTopN(List<Data> dataList, int n) {
    Map<String, Data> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Data data: dataList) {
        String key = data.getGroup();
        if(key != null) map.merge(key, data, MAX);
    }

    if(map.size() <= n) {
        return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    }
    else {
        PriorityQueue<Data> top = new PriorityQueue<>(n, BY_SCORE);
        for(Data d: map.values()) {
            top.add(d);
            if(top.size() > n) top.remove();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(top);
    }
}
```

Note that the `BinaryOperator.maxBy(…)` is using the ascending order as basis and also the priority queue now needs the ascending order, as we’re removing the smallest elements such that the top *n* remain in the queue for the result. Therefore, `reversed()` has been removed from the `Comparator` here.

Using a priority queue provides a benefit if *n* is small, especially in comparison to the map’s size. If *n* is rather large or expected to be close to the map’s size, it is likely more efficient to use

```java
List<Data> top = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
top.sort(BY_SCORE.reversed());
top.subList(n, top.size()).clear();
return top;
```

which sorts all of the map’s values in descending order and removes the excess elements. This can be combined with the code handling the `map.size() <= n` scenario:

```java
public List<Data> getTopN(List<Data> dataList, int n) {
    Map<String, Data> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Data data: dataList) {
        String key = data.getGroup();
        if(key != null) map.merge(key, data, MAX);
    }

    List<Data> top = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    if(top.size() > n) {
        top.sort(BY_SCORE.reversed());
        top.subList(n, top.size()).clear();
    }
    return top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you much detailed explanantion. Any idea on the big o or other performance metrics ?

Comment: There are three factors, the source list size (let’s call it `l`), the limit `n`, and the number of groups, i.e. size of the map, (let’s call it `m`). The first has `O(l + m × log n)`, the 2nd has `O(l + m × log m)`(**¹**). When you don’t know anything about these value, the upper bound for both, `m` and `n`, is `l`, so for the worst case, you have to consider them all to be the same, ending up at `O(n × log n)`, which is the unavoidable worst case for both approaches and the formally correct answer. In practice, the second has a better average case and low-level factors.

Comment: (**¹**)  Now you should see why the first is preferable when `n` is known to be rather small and the second when `n` might be large.

Comment: it is returning is ascending order for priority queue solution

Comment: The priority queue solution focuses on just providing the *max n* elements, not providing them in any particular order. Seeing an ascending order is just coincidence, the expression `new ArrayList<>(top)` does not guaranty any order. Mind that in the `map.size() <= n` case, it will even return the elements in the unspecified hash map’s order. If you want the result to be sorted, use the second approach. But mind that the version posted in the answer also doesn’t sort when not necessary. If you want the result to be always sorted, you have to move the `sort` call before the `if` statement.